# Split a file into multiple files based on column value

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powerquery

I want to split the below file into multiple files based on content;

**Input file:**

```
    HC05361         3036690000002020072814093990 R
    DC05361         00100001CD  03113      075992733625
    HC05362         3036690000002020072814103991 R
    DC05362         00100001CD  03113      075992733625
    HC05615         3024173024172020091408223795 R
    DC05615         00100001NDL 00016      856115004682
    DC05615         002000011   295013     825646252404
    DC05615         003000011   295617     825646248490
```

Output files:

File1:

```
    HC05361         3036690000002020072814093990 R
    DC05361         00100001CD  03113      075992733625
```

File2:

```
    HC05362         3036690000002020072814103991 R
    DC05362         00100001CD  03113      075992733625
```

File3:

```
    HC05615         3024173024172020091408223795 R
    DC05615         00100001NDL 00016      856115004682
    DC05615         002000011   295013     825646252404
    DC05615         003000011   295617     825646248490
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, but I think you may need to provide more information.

Like...

- What you want the filenames to be?
- What you know about the data

  - For example, do you always want to split on lines that start with `HC`? Are the values in the first column always going to be in the form `HC#####`?

Making a few assumptions, this is a basic example of what you could do.

This will iterate through every line in the file. If the line starts with `HC#####`, then it outputs that line and every following line to a file with that name. When it reaches a new `HC#####` value, it changes that to the file name:

```
$data = Get-Content .\sample.txt
foreach ($line in $data) {
    if ($line -match '^HC[0-9]+') {
        $fileName = "$($Matches[0]).txt"
    }
    Add-Content -Value $line -Path $fileName
}
```

This is assuming the first line will always provide us a filename.

It's also assuming that you want to split on lines starting with `HC`

It's also not performing any sort of exception handling.

Comment: Thank you, Chad for the quick response, yes I want to split based on HC, and the file name should be HC#####.

Comment: also I'll not have input file name static, so it might be one or more than one big files. Want to keep that file in output folder.